# Problem with Pidgin and Launcher in Unity 3D

Tags: launcher, pidgin

I have another problem. After I start Pidgin, if I minimize it, Pidgin don't have the little arrow in the Launcher showing me it's running. It shows like it's not running. Any solution please?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

You don't see Pidgin in the launcher since it should be integrated in the Message-Menu:

[image: screenshot]

I'm not sure, but maybe if you delete the file `/usr/share/indicators/messages/applications/pidgin`, you could restore the arrow behaviour you wish.
To check if my suggestion works, try moving the file first, so you can restore if it's not working.

Comment: Ok, and if i want to be in Launcher and maximized fromt there, what i cant do?

Comment: Works for a few seconds, when i minimize it, it show the little arow in Launcher. I quit Pidgin and i start it again and now if i minimize it, Pidgin dont have the little arow in Launcher....                                                     i quit pidgin, i start it from terminal, i minimize it and nothing happens...no output from terminal when minimize Pidgin... i minimize it pressing the "-" next to the orange "x"

Comment: @Adrian: I added a proposal in my answer; not sure if it will work.

Comment: After i restart the computer, Pidgin work again http://i.imgur.com/OTQBl.png What you say @igi ? and pidgin appears in the Message-Menu to! if it is assumed that they should not appear in the launcher, when you minimize the chat windows how make them appear again?

Comment: @Adrian: I added an image to my answer to better explain.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to open up Pidgin again, after minimizing, I installed the Hotkeys plugin and set the "Toggle List" hot-key.  This way I can still use Unity.

But that does not solve the problem with the missing indicator; so you still can't tell if Pidgin is running, without hitting the hot-key.

Answer (score 0):

The icon you are talking about was shown in the "Notification Area" applet, which was displayed on the Gnome Panel. However, Unity does not use the Gnome Panel, and does not show any Notification Icons, I have the same problem with Emesene :\ 
I just keep it open in the background, or you can switch back to Ubuntu Classic.